# Umbraco cannot connect to aws rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, umbraco, amazon-rds

I have see this issue on other posts, but none of the suggestions have helped. My client has an Umbraco site hosted on AWS with MySql RDS.  I am able to connect to their database through mysql workbench and view the data.  But, when I start their site up in vs 2017 iisexpress I get: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxad5.png)

I have created a new user in database, and that did not work.  I changed the connection string all around in many ways with no luck.  I have provided my ip to aws to be able to access.

Comment: Umbraco cannot start. A connection string is configured but Umbraco cannot connect to the database.

Comment: Have you checked if it is IP restricted somehow?